# WinRT Settings Popup implemented in base class isn't visible?

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I'm trying to make a Setting flyout easily accessible in all pages.  I looked at the Settings example at http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/App-settings-sample-1f762f49/sourcecode?fileId=50851&pathId=2033699455.

However there are about a dozen functions and it's just dumb to have to copy/paste/maintain an undetermined number of copies of the same code in each page.  So I took the code for the popup and put it in a base class that inherits from `LayoutAwarePage` base class.  My pages then inherit from this new class.  Ex:

```
// Base class declaration that includes settings flyout code
public class SettingsFlyoutAwarePage : myApp.Common.LayoutAwarePage
{
    // Settings flyout code here
}

// Page declaration
public sealed partial class GroupedItemsPage : myApp.Common.SettingsFlyoutAwarePage
{
    // Standard working page stuff here
}
```

Here is the actual code to create popup that IS being called and executed in the `SettingsFlyoutAwarePage` base class, which is identical to the sample code, but nothing actually appears on screen:

```
    void onSettingsCommand(IUICommand command)
    {
        // Create a Popup window which will contain our flyout.
        settingsPopup = new Popup();
        settingsPopup.Closed += OnPopupClosed;
        Window.Current.Activated += OnWindowActivated;
        settingsPopup.IsLightDismissEnabled = true;
        settingsPopup.Width = settingsWidth;
        settingsPopup.Height = windowBounds.Height;

        // Add the proper animation for the panel.
        settingsPopup.ChildTransitions = new TransitionCollection();
        settingsPopup.ChildTransitions.Add(new PaneThemeTransition()
        {
            Edge = (SettingsPane.Edge == SettingsEdgeLocation.Right) ?
                   EdgeTransitionLocation.Right :
                   EdgeTransitionLocation.Left
        });

        // Create a SettingsFlyout the same dimenssions as the Popup.
        SettingsFlyout mypane = new SettingsFlyout();
        mypane.Width = settingsWidth;
        mypane.Height = windowBounds.Height;

        // Place the SettingsFlyout inside our Popup window.
        settingsPopup.Child = mypane;

        // Let's define the location of our Popup.
        settingsPopup.SetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty, SettingsPane.Edge == SettingsEdgeLocation.Right ? (windowBounds.Width - settingsWidth) : 0);
        settingsPopup.SetValue(Canvas.TopProperty, 0);
        settingsPopup.IsOpen = true;
    }
```

While I can step through all the code and it all appears to execute just fine, I never actually see the flyout appear.  Is it at least theoretically possible to do this from an inherited base class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you implement the `onCommandsRequested` function as described in demo?

```
void onCommandsRequested(SettingsPane settingsPane, SettingsPaneCommandsRequestedEventArgs eventArgs)
        {
            UICommandInvokedHandler handler = new UICommandInvokedHandler(onSettingsCommand);

            SettingsCommand generalCommand = new SettingsCommand("DefaultsId", "Defaults", handler);
            eventArgs.Request.ApplicationCommands.Add(generalCommand);
        }
```

Comment: It turned out to be even sillier/simpler than that.  I didn't carry over the setting of the windowBounds property.  There were never any errors/complaints, it just didn't display.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If this helps anyone, here is a Settings flyout-aware class that you can inherit your XAML pages from.  Of course you still have to implement the popup itself [(demo code link)](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/App-settings-sample-1f762f49/sourcecode?fileId=50851&pathId=2033699455)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.UI.ApplicationSettings;
using Windows.UI.Popups;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Animation;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;

namespace MyApp.Common
{
    [Windows.Foundation.Metadata.WebHostHidden]
    public class MyAppBasePage : MyApp.Common.LayoutAwarePage
    {

        public MyAppBasePage()
        {
        }

        private bool isSettingCharmEventRegistered;

        // Used to determine the correct height to ensure our custom UI fills the screen.
        private Rect windowBounds;

        // Desired width for the settings UI. UI guidelines specify this should be 346 or 646 depending on your needs.
        private double settingsWidth = 646;

        // This is the container that will hold our custom content.
        private Popup settingsPopup;

        protected override void OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnNavigatedFrom(e);

            // Added to make sure the event handler for CommandsRequested is cleaned up before other scenarios.
            if (this.isSettingCharmEventRegistered)
            {
                SettingsPane.GetForCurrentView().CommandsRequested -= onCommandsRequested;
                this.isSettingCharmEventRegistered = false;
            }

            // Unregister the event that listens for events when the window size is updated.
            Window.Current.SizeChanged -= OnWindowSizeChanged;
        }

        protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnNavigatedTo(e);

            windowBounds = Window.Current.Bounds;

            // Added to listen for events when the window size is updated.
            Window.Current.SizeChanged += OnWindowSizeChanged;

            // Added to make sure the event handler for CommandsRequested is cleaned up before other scenarios.
            if (!this.isSettingCharmEventRegistered)
            {
                SettingsPane.GetForCurrentView().CommandsRequested += onCommandsRequested;
                this.isSettingCharmEventRegistered = true;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Invoked when the window size is updated.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender">Instance that triggered the event.</param>
        /// <param name="e">Event data describing the conditions that led to the event.</param>
        void OnWindowSizeChanged(object sender, Windows.UI.Core.WindowSizeChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            windowBounds = Window.Current.Bounds;
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// We use the window's activated event to force closing the Popup since a user maybe interacted with
        /// something that didn't normally trigger an obvious dismiss.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender">Instance that triggered the event.</param>
        /// <param name="e">Event data describing the conditions that led to the event.</param>
        private void OnWindowActivated(object sender, Windows.UI.Core.WindowActivatedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.WindowActivationState == Windows.UI.Core.CoreWindowActivationState.Deactivated)
            {
                settingsPopup.IsOpen = false;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// When the Popup closes we no longer need to monitor activation changes.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender">Instance that triggered the event.</param>
        /// <param name="e">Event data describing the conditions that led to the event.</param>
        void OnPopupClosed(object sender, object e)
        {
            Window.Current.Activated -= OnWindowActivated;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// This event is generated when the user opens the settings pane. During this event, append your
        /// SettingsCommand objects to the available ApplicationCommands vector to make them available to the
        /// SettingsPange UI.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="settingsPane">Instance that triggered the event.</param>
        /// <param name="eventArgs">Event data describing the conditions that led to the event.</param>
        void onCommandsRequested(SettingsPane settingsPane, SettingsPaneCommandsRequestedEventArgs eventArgs)
        {
            UICommandInvokedHandler handler = new UICommandInvokedHandler(onSettingsCommand);

            SettingsCommand generalCommand = new SettingsCommand("DefaultsId", "Defaults", handler);
            eventArgs.Request.ApplicationCommands.Add(generalCommand);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// This the event handler for the "Defaults" button added to the settings charm. This method
        /// is responsible for creating the Popup window will use as the container for our settings Flyout.
        /// The reason we use a Popup is that it gives us the "light dismiss" behavior that when a user clicks away 
        /// from our custom UI it just dismisses.  This is a principle in the Settings experience and you see the
        /// same behavior in other experiences like AppBar. 
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="command"></param>
        void onSettingsCommand(IUICommand command)
        {
            // Create a Popup window which will contain our flyout.
            settingsPopup = new Popup();
            settingsPopup.Closed += OnPopupClosed;
            Window.Current.Activated += OnWindowActivated;
            settingsPopup.IsLightDismissEnabled = true;
            settingsPopup.Width = settingsWidth;
            settingsPopup.Height = windowBounds.Height;

            // Add the proper animation for the panel.
            settingsPopup.ChildTransitions = new TransitionCollection();
            settingsPopup.ChildTransitions.Add(new PaneThemeTransition()
            {
                Edge = (SettingsPane.Edge == SettingsEdgeLocation.Right) ?
                       EdgeTransitionLocation.Right :
                       EdgeTransitionLocation.Left
            });

            // Create a SettingsFlyout the same dimenssions as the Popup.
            SettingsFlyout mypane = new SettingsFlyout();
            mypane.Width = settingsWidth;
            mypane.Height = windowBounds.Height;

            // Place the SettingsFlyout inside our Popup window.
            settingsPopup.Child = mypane;

            // Let's define the location of our Popup.
            settingsPopup.SetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty, SettingsPane.Edge == SettingsEdgeLocation.Right ? (windowBounds.Width - settingsWidth) : 0);
            settingsPopup.SetValue(Canvas.TopProperty, 0);
            settingsPopup.IsOpen = true;
        }
    }
}
```